# Is there a AAD login web test that I can use for the Azure availability test as the one I am using is randomly generating context parameter errors?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-active-directory, webtest

We are running a web test that uses AAD to login to a web site. When run via Visual Studio the web test runs correctly. However, when run in Azure availability this generates missing context parameter errors. I have attached the error call stack. This is causing availability dips. The error is not specific to a Azure region. I need a web test that works.

There is no try catch mechanism in web tests so I cannot filter out such errors.

I can't upload or paste the web test but its a Azure AAD login web test.

I expect the web test to work. However, I get the following errors:

2 primary requests, 0 dependant requests and 0 conditional rules failed

> Exception (subtype 'WebTestException') occured at (UTC) for Uri 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/kmsi', step #5 with the error 'Context parameter 'FormPostParam1.ctx' not found in test context', exception text 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting.WebTestException: Context parameter 'FormPostParam1.ctx' not found in test context   at 
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.HelperMethods.UpdateBindingSites(WebTestCaseContext testCaseContext, String preBoundString)   at 
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.WebTestInstrumentedTransaction.PerformRequestDataBinding()   at 
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.WebTestInstrumentedTransaction.Execute(WebTestCaseContext testCaseContext, AsyncCallback completionCallback, Object callerState)', stack trace '   at 
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.HelperMethods.UpdateBindingSites(WebTestCaseContext testCaseContext, String preBoundString)   at 
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.WebTestInstrumentedTransaction.PerformRequestDataBinding()   at 
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.WebTestInstrumentedTransaction.Execute(WebTestCaseContext testCaseContext, AsyncCallback completionCallback, Object callerState)'.
>
> Exception (subtype 'WebTestException') occured at (UTC) for Uri '', step #6 with the error 'Context parameter '$HIDDEN1.code' not found in test context', exception text 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting.WebTestException: Context parameter '$HIDDEN1.code' not found in test context   at 
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.HelperMethods.UpdateBindingSites(WebTestCaseContext testCaseContext, String preBoundString)   at 
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.WebTestInstrumentedTransaction.PerformRequestDataBinding()   at 
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.WebTestInstrumentedTransaction.Execute(WebTestCaseContext testCaseContext, AsyncCallback completionCallback, Object callerState)', stack trace '   at 
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.HelperMethods.UpdateBindingSites(WebTestCaseContext testCaseContext, String preBoundString)   at 
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.WebTestInstrumentedTransaction.PerformRequestDataBinding()   at 
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.WebTestInstrumentedTransaction.Execute(WebTestCaseContext testCaseContext, AsyncCallback completionCallback, Object callerState)'.

Comment: A missing context parameter normally means that one of the preceding requests did not work as expected. Possibly an extraction rule has its `Required` property set to `False`. The second error about a missing "hidden" context parameter also suggests a request returned an error and not the wanted output.

Comment: You are right that Required is set to false but this appears to be intentional. Appears that https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2 is not returning some parameters as expected. Anyone has a web test that works with https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2?

Comment: If a context parameter (CP) is used in a request and the `Required` property is set to false in the extraction rule for that CP then ask yourself how else can that CP be given a value. Look carefully at the response that has the extraction rule, it may contain an error message or some other message explaining what has (not) happened. I suggest the request that throws the missing CP messages is not important, look at the earlier requests that should have given the CP a value.